# Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'base_grand_total' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: order-grid

I've been able to add a few custom attributes to the sales order grid (sku, custom name). I am able to filter correctly. When I add the customer email, I can add and filter it too, but then if I filter by a total (e.g. base grand total) I get the error above. Other solutions suggest using filter_index to remove this ambiguity but this hasn't helped, presumably because it's on a field I'm not adding (grand total) - so this is not due to ambiguous entity_id. How do I make it use the specific total field?

Here are the helpful parts:

Observer

```
 class Kaska_ExtendedGrid_Model_Observer
{

public function salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore($observer)
{

    $collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
    $select = $collection->getSelect();

    $select->join('m_sales_flat_order', '`m_sales_flat_order`.entity_id = `main_table`.entity_id', array('email'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('`m_sales_flat_order`.customer_email')));

    $select->joinLeft(array('payment' => $collection->getTable('sales/order_payment')), 'payment.parent_id=main_table.entity_id', array('payment_method' => 'method'));

    $select->join('m_sales_flat_order_item','`m_sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id', array('sku' => new Zend_Db_Expr('`m_sales_flat_order_item`.sku'),'name'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('`m_sales_flat_order_item`.name') ));

    $select->join('m_catalog_product_entity_varchar', '`m_catalog_product_entity_varchar`.attribute_id=163 AND `m_catalog_product_entity_varchar`.entity_id = `m_sales_flat_order_item`.`product_id`', array('attr'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('`m_catalog_product_entity_varchar`.value')));

    $select->group('main_table.entity_id');


}


public function filterEmail($collection, $column)
{

    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }
    $collection->getSelect()->having(
        "`m_sales_flat_order`.customer_email like ?", "%$value%");
    return $this;
}


.... filterSku etc
```

layout.xml

```
<sales_order_grid_update_handle>
    <reference name="sales_order.grid">
        <action method="addColumnAfter">
            <columnId>payment_method</columnId>
            <arguments>
                <header>Payment Method</header>
                <index>payment_method</index>
                <filter_index>payment.method</filter_index>
                <type>text</type>
            </arguments>
            <after>shipping_name</after>
        </action>
        <action method="addColumnAfter">
            <columnId>email</columnId>
            <arguments helper="kaska_extendedgrid/getEmailColumnParams" />
            <after>payment_method</after>
        </action>
```

Helper file

```
public function getEmailColumnParams(){
    return array(
    'header'    => 'Customer Email',
    'index'     => 'email',
    'type'        => 'text',
    'filter_index'=>'m_sales_flat_order.customer_email',
}
```

I also tried locally overriding the _prepareColumns of Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

```
$this->addColumn('base_grand_total', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Base)'),
        'index' => 'base_grand_total',
        'type'  => 'currency',
        'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
     'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order.base_grand_total'
    ));
```

***EDIT***
After some help from below, the culprit was another extension's overriding of the order grid preparecolumns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this by using `Zend_Db_Expr`, not sure it will fix.

```
$this->addColumn('base_grand_total', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Base)'),
        'index' => 'base_grand_total',
        'type'  => 'currency',
        'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
     'filter_index' => new Zend_Db_Expr("main_table.base_grand_total")
    ));
```

Comment: I added that line in `app/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php` but it didn't fix it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Question: Did you override _prepareColumns callinf parent::_prepareColumns() inside of it?

Comment: Because the way you used is the right one. Just make sure you are not adding the same column two times by calling the parent's method.

Comment: At the end of the local _prepareColumns is `return parent::_prepareColumns();`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yep, you are probably adding the same field two times. Try overriding the whole method by copying its content from the parent and without calling the parent. My idea is that you are calling the addColumn two times. And your error is coming from the parent's method.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not because of two add Columns, because I removed the local _prepareColumns entirely. I also tried editing the core file (just as an experiment) and it's the same ambiguous field error.

Comment: Try specifying in the Zend_Db mode the index param too, just to make sure it is not coming from the fields list instead of then fields filter.

Comment: it was because a third party extension had their own preparecolumns, so you pointed me in the right direction, thanks